# MYSQL Query with 2 columns in Table A related to 1 column in Table B

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Tables, User and Mail.

In User Table i have 2 columns that i will use, the ID column which makes the relation with the Mail Table and it is the Index of User Table and the Name column.

In Mail Table i have Receiver Column and Sender Column. Both columns, Receiver and Sender have a number that relates to the ID Column in the User Table. In the User Table is where the name columns resides and i want to make a query that shows me the Receiver and Sender Columns but with the name of the user, not the ID.

Up to this point i have this:

```
SELECT name AS Send, name AS Receive FROM mail,user WHERE sender=guid;
```

I know there is still a part of the query missing but i can not figure out what else to put to tell it to show in the SEND output column the name of the sender and in the RECEIVE output column the name of the receiver.

Comment: Format your question so that your table names and table columns are more clear please.

Comment: Done. Should look better now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to join on your User table twice.  Your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT u1.name as send, u2.name as receive
FROM mail m
INNER JOIN user u1 on m.sender = u1.guid
INNER JOIN user u2 on m.receiver = u2.guid
```

That should do it for you!

Comment: Well, usually that's a matter of indexing.  Make sure you put nonclustered index on the mail.sender column and the mail.reciever column, and that should speed things up considerably.  Also, if your user.guid column isn't an auto_incremented integer (and thus your mail.sender and mail.receiver columns would be integers), I'd recommend making it one - joins on integers tend to be very fast.